# certificate assistant - the specified keychain could not be found

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

I am using Keychain Access on a Mac, trying to create a new certificate for iphone app signing. My existing cert is nearly expired. I keep getting the error "the specified keychain could not be found".

Here are my steps:

1. Open Keychain Access on Mac OS X 10.7.5.
2. Select Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.
3. User Email Address and Common Name are pre-populated. I leave them as-is. I change the radio button from "Emailed to the CA" to "Saved to disk".
4. Click Continue.
5. Whether I use the default filename or type a different name, I always get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a question for either superuser or serverfault

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18589759/741626