# Swift 3 error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, swift3, cocoapods

For my project written initially in Swift 2 that worked well, after migration to Swift 3, I still can run with the simulator but if I want to run on a device, I have this error

```
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

Of course, my certificate is still valide and the device is included. I tried with another device and it still the same.

The error appear during the "Run custom shell script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'"

```
sent 139 bytes  received 20 bytes  318.00 bytes/sec
total size is 288890  speedup is 1816.92
Code Signing ...ParseStarterProject.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: ....

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign ....  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "...ParseStarterProject.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework"
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

I tried to use cocoapods-deintegrate and reinstall all Pods but the problem still here.

Any kind of contributions is appreciated.

Comment: Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845169/error-when-trying-to-obtain-a-certificate-the-specified-item-could-not-be-found) would help

Comment: @EmilDavid I don't think I have a problem with my certificate because the certificate is valid. Do you think, I have to delete and request again?

Comment: After some Googling, other devs who experienced this issue, it was related to their certificate and even judging from your trace, code signing is definitely related to your certificate. It may be provisioning profiles or something along those lines.. Try requesting a new one.

Comment: @Kibo Are you able to resolve the issue?