# How to reset app signing process in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I [can’t sign my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313794/signing-app-in-xcode-specified-item-could-not-be-found-in-the-keychain) in Xcode, therefore I’m looking for a way to completely reset everything I have to in order to be able to sign it. I did

- Revoke all certificates in the certificates, identifiers & profiles menu in http://developer.apple.com
- Delete all provisioning profiles in http://developer.apple.com
- Delete all iPhone development and iPhone distribution certificates in my keychain
- Delete the provisioning profiles in Xcode

and then

- Create new certificates in developer.apple.com
- Create new provisioning profiles in http://developer.apple.com
- Download certificates and add them to my keychain
- Use new provisioning profile in Xcode

Unfortunately I’m still encountering [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313794/signing-app-in-xcode-specified-item-could-not-be-found-in-the-keychain) (item can't be found in keychain), which leads me to the assumption that I did not successfully reset all the app signing process in Xcode. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue last week with my own app.  I did multiple things to fix this at once, so I'll tell you what I did, and hopefully one of them works.

Try:
Removing and deleting all certificates, devices, and provisioning profiles from your developer account and recreate them.
Download the developer and distribution certificates, and right click on them to add them to your keychain.
Download your provisioning profiles to your mac and right click on them to add them to whatever they get added to.
MAKE SURE YOU HAVE AN ACTUAL DEVICE ADDED TO YOUR DEVELOPER PROFILE ON DEVELOPER.APPLE.COM
In xcode, go to accounts and make sure you are signed in with your developer account and you have the correct profiles downloaded.  In your app's build settings/signing settings, make sure you don't have your "Personal Team" profile ANYWHERE that it asks for some sort of signing/developer/provisioning Profile.