# Xamarin cannot build to device - Tool exited with code: 1. Output: error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, codesign

I am trying to build an iOS app in Debug|iPhone configuration on Xamarin Mac, but I am getting:

`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: Tool exited with code: 1. Output: error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.`

This all started when I had to reset my default keychain and lost my certificates.  I've tried fixing it by:

- Creating a new certificate manually (ensuring I had "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" when requesting the certificate from the certificate authority as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19160225/2301021))
- Creating a certificate using xcode 8.3.1 (exporting this certificate onto another machine lets me build fine on that machine)
- Importing my certificates from my old keychain (each time I created a new certificate I ensured to update and download the provisioning profile)
- exporting a working certificate from another user on another machine and importing it onto my machine
- uninstalling Xamarin studio, deleting the folders mentioned [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/#Uninstall_Xamarin_Studio), and installing Xamarin Studio 6.1.3 + Xamarin.iOS 10.4.0.123 (was using  6.1.3 + 10.2.1.5 previously)
- uninstalling Xcode 8.1 and installing Xcode 8.3.1
- installing visual studio for mac (this gave me a different error "EnsureBindingRedirects task failed unexpectedly" - likely a separate bug)

The fact it failed to build when using a known working certificate/provisioning profile combo on another machine leads me to think that Xamarin is having a problem finding the certificate when doing the build, even though it sees the certificate and provisioning profile in Project Options -> iOS Bundle Signing.  There could also be an issue in the Keychain somewhere.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following:

1. `security dump-keychain -d login.keychain` to list all the items in my keychain
2. Noticed there was an extra certificate that was not showing up in Keychain Access
3. Deleted this item using `security delete-identity`
4. Did `diskutil resetUserPermissions / $(id -u)` and restarted my Mac

I'm not sure if steps 1-3 are necessary, so if you are having this issue I would try step 4 first and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio on a mac and my solution was to shut down Visual Studio and start it again after logging out of Apple Developer Account in the visual studio preferences.