# xcode 8.3 error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: xcode, macos-sierra

I can't sign apps on macOS 10.12.4 when I trying to run a project on xcode I get

error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

clearing keychain not fixing anything

can you help please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to obtain a certificate: The specified item could not be found in the keychain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845169/error-when-trying-to-obtain-a-certificate-the-specified-item-could-not-be-found)

Comment: @DanielStorm this is old question also different now there is a new thing called "Automatically manage signing"

Comment: I have been having the same issue too. Anyone any sucessfull experience?

Comment: Are you able to compile when a simulator is selected vs when your device or 'general' is selected next to schemas?

Comment: @Sasho in "keychain access" I have noticed "My certificates" is empty this section not suppose to be blank .

Comment: I am able to compile when I choose a simulator, but not the others...

Comment: @Sasho simulator doesn't require code signing

Comment: tested on xcode 9 beta 3 still hasn't been fixed yet

Comment: @bader did you recently migrate to a new mac by chance?

Comment: yes I did copied old mac files into my new machine via migration assistant

Comment: @bader same here. I think we have the same issue. I will keep you posted if I can figure it out.

Comment: @bader I completely uninstalled xcode and installed it again and the same issue happened.

Comment: @RayHunter It's not Xcode fault I did uninstalled it manually many times and I get same result every time .. I think our problem in keychain access if you look into "My Certificates" you will find it empty .. did you report it to [Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) ?

Comment: @bader that is the same for me. I have uninstalled the keys, certs and xcode and still having the same issue. I have exported the accounts from my other mac and imported them to my new one and I still have the same issue. I have not reported it to apple.

Comment: @RayHunter I did reported it to apple they working on a fix but I didn't mention migration assistant part

Comment: @bader do you have a link to where you reported it?

Comment: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @bader I ended up reformatting my mac to get it working. I asked a bunch of people and no one could tell me how to fix it. That was my last resort. I believe the migration with the keychain caused the issue somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. In my case the cause was a VPN auth token (SafeNet) that I had plugged into a USB port. When I removed it, suddenly the code signing worked again.

It seems that the code signing process had some trouble (timeout?) accessing the keychain. So the hint is: remove or kill everything (hardware, software, apps) that could interfere with keychain access.

I know that this answer does not cover all the cases for this error, but one of them for sure ;)