# When l use go get l can't download package, x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided; SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates error: -25300

Tags: macos, go, ca

the problem picture is below:

```rust
# 
$ go get github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger
go get: module github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger/@v/list": x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided; SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates error: -25300
```

MyMac os version :10.13.1 (17B1003

go version: go1.16.5 darwin/amd64

and my go env is:

```
$ go env                                
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/caibin/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/caibin/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/caibin/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/caibin/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="off"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/zt/qmccm9gs2f98ms8ynt7y4mg40000gn/T/go-build4199856293=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

l had set goproxy and GO111MODULE, but it is no use

Comment: l change my go version to 1.18, my terminal output:                                                              
   dyld:     Symbol not found: _SecTrustEvaluateWithError
  Referenced from: /usr/local/go/bin/go
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    41536 abort      go get github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message:

SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates function is to: Obtains an array of all certificates that have trust settings in a specific trust settings domain.

The error code -25300 means errSecItemNotFound, which is a standard keychain error.

The error indicates that something wrong when trying to get certificates chain to trust some certificate.

You can try to install CA with `sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates`

If this doesn't work, you might need to troubleshoot it by searching keyword "Mac" and -25300.

Some links below for your reference:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45326

[Error when trying to obtain a certificate: The specified item could not be found in the keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845169/error-when-trying-to-obtain-a-certificate-the-specified-item-could-not-be-found)