# error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain GitHub CI Run

Tags: ios, github-actions, cicd

Before 24th April I was able to generate build using GitHub CI.
on 24th the Developer account's certificate got expired and now I started getting below error:

*error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.*

[image]

I have updated my `CODE_SIGNING_PRIVATE_KEY` in gitHub -> Settings -> Actions
Updated the provisioning profile as well but still getting the same issue.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Please include your relevant workflow in your question.

Comment: Is that all? What about your runner? Please add that section too. Thanks!

Comment: In your listed steps, those commands are only related to codesigning. Apparently, some other step should be setting up your keychain from your environment secrets. Or, if it's a self-hosted runner then the keychain must've already been set up manually. Please add these details in your question also.

Comment: There's a step in your workflow i.e. "**Setup code signing**", what does it do? It's output is being used in the `codesign` command later on with `-s` flag. As it's a custom action, please take a look at it whether it's setting up any keychain in there.

Comment: Also, relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845169/error-when-trying-to-obtain-a-certificate-the-specified-item-could-not-be-found